# Icons inside the ActionColumn are zoomed after composer update

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.4

My environment: CentOS 7, PHP 7.4, Apache 2.4, yii2:dev-master

I performed a few composer updates of my yii2 project today and after that I noticed a strange display of the ActionColumn icons. On some GridView tables (not all) the icons are zoomed (in or out) depending on the width of the column header. I attached three pictures, with different widths of the header.

[image: tiny icons][image: wide icons][image: wider icons]

Any ideea on how to stop this behaviour and not have the icons zoomed anymore?

I paste here the output of `composer show`:

```
behat/gherkin                       v4.8.0             Gherkin DSL parser for PHP
bower-asset/bootstrap               v3.4.1             The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
bower-asset/inputmask               3.3.11             Inputmask is a javascript library which creates an input mask.  Inputmask can run against vanilla javascript, jQuery and jqlite.
bower-asset/jquery                  3.5.1             
bower-asset/jquery-colorbox         dev-master 38c2540 jQuery lightbox and modal window plugin
bower-asset/jquery-ui               1.12.1            
bower-asset/punycode                v1.3.2            
bower-asset/yii2-pjax               dev-master c39f239
cebe/markdown                       1.2.1              A super fast, highly extensible markdown parser for PHP
codeception/base                    2.5.6              BDD-style testing framework
codeception/phpunit-wrapper         7.8.2              PHPUnit classes used by Codeception
codeception/stub                    2.1.0              Flexible Stub wrapper for PHPUnit's Mock Builder
codeception/verify                  0.3.3              BDD assertion library for PHPUnit
doctrine/instantiator               1.4.0              A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
dompdf/dompdf                       dev-master 0ccafeb DOMPDF is a CSS 2.1 compliant HTML to PDF converter
ezyang/htmlpurifier                 v4.13.0            Standards compliant HTML filter written in PHP
fakerphp/faker                      v1.13.0            Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
guzzlehttp/psr7                     1.7.0              PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
himiklab/yii2-colorbox-widget       1.0.3              Customizable lightbox widget for Yii2
kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput        v5.1.5             An enhanced HTML 5 file input for Bootstrap 3.x with features for file preview for many file types, multiple selection, ajax uploads, and more.
kartik-v/yii2-date-range            dev-master 2261757 An advanced Yii 2 date range picker input for based on bootstrap-daterangepicker plugin.
kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base           v2.0.5             Base library and foundation components for all Yii2 Krajee extensions.
kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker     dev-master 9825762 Enhanced Yii2 wrapper for the bootstrap datepicker plugin (sub repo split from yii2-widgets).
kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker dev-master f64114b Enhanced Yii2 wrapper for the bootstrap datetimepicker plugin (sub repo split from yii2-widgets)
kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput      v1.0.9             An enhanced FileInput widget for Bootstrap 3.x & 4.x with file preview, multiple selection, and more features (sub repo split from yii2-widgets)
laminas/laminas-escaper             2.7.0              Securely and safely escape HTML, HTML attributes, JavaScript, CSS, and URLs
maennchen/zipstream-php             2.1.0              ZipStream is a library for dynamically streaming dynamic zip files from PHP without writing to the disk at all on the server.
markbaker/complex                   2.0.0              PHP Class for working with complex numbers
markbaker/matrix                    2.1.2              PHP Class for working with matrices
myclabs/deep-copy                   1.10.2             Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
myclabs/php-enum                    1.8.0              PHP Enum implementation
nemmo/yii2-attachments              1.0.0-beta.3       Extension for file uploading and attaching to the models
phar-io/manifest                    1.0.3              Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                     2.0.1              Library for handling version information and constraints
phenx/php-font-lib                  0.5.2              A library to read, parse, export and make subsets of different types of font files.
phenx/php-svg-lib                   v0.3.3             A library to read, parse and export to PDF SVG files.
phpdocumentor/reflection-common     2.2.0              Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock   5.2.2              With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise retrieve information that is embedded in a DocBlock.
phpdocumentor/type-resolver         1.4.0              A PSR-5 based resolver of Class names, Types and Structural Element Names
phpoffice/phpspreadsheet            1.17.1             PHPSpreadsheet - Read, Create and Write Spreadsheet documents in PHP - Spreadsheet engine
phpoffice/phpword                   dev-master 1bd7cd6 PHPWord - A pure PHP library for reading and writing word processing documents (OOXML, ODF, RTF, HTML, PDF)
phpspec/php-diff                    v1.1.3             A comprehensive library for generating differences between two hashable objects (strings or arrays).
phpspec/prophecy                    1.12.2             Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage           6.1.4              Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.
phpunit/php-file-iterator           2.0.3              FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template           1.2.1              Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                   2.1.3              Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream            3.1.2              Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                     7.5.20             The PHP Unit Testing framework.
psr/container                       1.1.1              Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/http-client                     1.0.1              Common interface for HTTP clients
psr/http-factory                    1.0.1              Common interfaces for PSR-7 HTTP message factories
psr/http-message                    1.0.1              Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/simple-cache                    1.0.1              Common interfaces for simple caching
ralouphie/getallheaders             3.0.3              A polyfill for getallheaders.
sabberworm/php-css-parser           8.3.1              Parser for CSS Files written in PHP
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup  1.0.2              Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                3.0.3              Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                      3.0.3              Diff implementation
sebastian/environment               4.2.4              Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                  3.1.3              Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state              2.0.0              Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator         3.0.4              Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/object-reflector          1.1.2              Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ones
sebastian/recursion-context         3.0.1              Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations       2.0.2              Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                   2.0.1              Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
squizlabs/php_codesniffer           3.5.8              PHP_CodeSniffer tokenizes PHP, JavaScript and CSS files and detects violations of a defined set of coding standards.
swiftmailer/swiftmailer             v5.4.12            Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/browser-kit                 v4.4.20            Simulates the behavior of a web browser, allowing you to make requests, click on links and submit forms programmatically
symfony/console                     v4.4.20            Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces
symfony/css-selector                v4.4.20            Converts CSS selectors to XPath expressions
symfony/dom-crawler                 v4.4.20            Eases DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents
symfony/event-dispatcher            v4.4.20            Provides tools that allow your application components to communicate with each other by dispatching events and listening to them
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts  v1.1.9             Generic abstractions related to dispatching event
symfony/finder                      v4.4.20            Finds files and directories via an intuitive fluent interface
symfony/polyfill-ctype              v1.22.1            Symfony polyfill for ctype functions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring           v1.22.1            Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php73              v1.22.1            Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.3+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php80              v1.22.1            Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/service-contracts           v2.2.0             Generic abstractions related to writing services
symfony/yaml                        v4.4.20            Loads and dumps YAML files
theseer/tokenizer                   1.2.0              A small library for converting tokenized PHP source code into XML and potentially other formats
twilio/sdk                          6.19.0             A PHP wrapper for Twilio's API
webmozart/assert                    1.10.0             Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
yiisoft/yii2                        dev-master 67b10cc Yii PHP Framework Version 2
yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap              2.0.10             The Twitter Bootstrap extension for the Yii framework
yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards       2.0.4              Yii PHP Framework Version 2 - Coding standard tools
yiisoft/yii2-composer               2.0.10             The composer plugin for Yii extension installer
yiisoft/yii2-debug                  2.0.14             The debugger extension for the Yii framework
yiisoft/yii2-faker                  2.0.5              Fixture generator. The Faker integration for the Yii framework.
yiisoft/yii2-gii                    dev-master aa5307c The Gii extension for the Yii framework
yiisoft/yii2-jui                    2.0.7              The Jquery UI extension for the Yii framework
yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer            2.0.7              The SwiftMailer integration for the Yii framework
```

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/18559

Comment: @Bizley
I've just ran a `composer update` and I got this 
```- Updating phpspec/prophecy (1.12.2 => 1.13.0):  Checking out be1996ed8a
- Updating yiisoft/yii2 dev-master (67b10cc => 91d01fc):  Checking out 91d01fc420```
Unfortunately though, the bug is still present. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the issue - just correct it by hand to see if it is ok, then revert the changes.

Comment: Ok, already merged, you can update your composer now.

Comment: Great! It is OK now. Thank you. If you post it as an answer I'll be glad to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Cheers, feel free to answer it yourself / close it since I did not provide any real answer, it was just a comment.